# SQL Server 2005 slows down as I keep adding rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005, performance

As a preface, I am brand new to using SQL Server 2005; I know how to use the SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT commands and that's about it. I am also using Express Edition on my local PC (E8400 processor, 8GB of DDR2-800, 2 x 640GB SATA-II HDD in RAID 1)

I have a table that I set up with 8 columns, all are NVARCHAR(Max) and I allow Null. I know in concept what a primary key is, but I don't have one (nor do I know how to set one up).

My VB.NET program that I'm working on is downloading a historical stock price chart from Yahoo, for every single ticker symbol in existence. The first 50,000 rows or so I added was super fast. Then I went to bed, and when I woke up it was still running - but the rate of row additions has slowed waaaaaay down; I noticed this around row 300,000. I always expected the rate of row addition to be constant over time, but obviously this is not so!

From browsing other Stack Overflow questions, I suspect my slow down is related to my piss-poor table setup. If this is the case, where should I begin first to fix this, and are there any good resources I could read up on to get started? I'm hoping this is something simple I can fix :)

In case it matters, this is how I'm adding rows:

```
cmdtext = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DateStamp FROM DailyPrice WHERE (DateStamp = '" +     datestamp + "' AND Ticker = '" + ticker + "')) INSERT INTO DailyPrice (Ticker,OpenPrice,ClosePrice,HighPrice,LowPrice,AdjustedClose,Volume,DateStamp) VALUES('" + ticker + "','" + openprice + "','" + closeprice + "','" + highprice + "','" + lowprice + "','" + adjustedclose + "','" + volume + "','" + datestamp + "')"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdtext, conn)
                howmanygotinserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

I iterate through that for every stinking row of the CSV file, which is around 30,000 rows per CSV file (and I have over 5000 of them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> with 8 columns, all are NVARCHAR(Max)

There's your first problem. Databases work best if you tell them what type of data you have, and choose the smallest datatype that works for your data. NVARCHAR(Max) is about the most inefficient choice you could have made.

> I don't have [a primary key] (nor do I know how to set one up).

And that's your second problem. On every insert you are checking to see if you already have inserted a row that has the same values as another row for certain columns. Because you haven't told the database to index those columns, it has to check the entire table each time, so your query gets slower and slower as the table grows. To add a primary key to an existing table you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY (Ticker, DateStamp)
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Fixing the datatypes alone just resulted in a MASSIVE improvement!  I will get the primary key implemented next! I really appreciate everyone's help, and all the answers have helped me - I wish I could accept them all!

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems:

1. Your table probably lacks appropriate indexes; and
2. You may be running inside a transaction.

You should have an index on (Ticker,DateStamp) and the check will be much faster. That being said, I wouldn't even do that check. If the INSERT fails, it fails. No biggie.

If you're running inside a transaction and not committing or doing save points then the temporary storage will get huge as you insert rows (because the database needs to be able to rollback any changes). Commit every 1000 rows or so. Either that or don't run inside a transaction.

Now, the next issue is how you're constructing the INSERT statement. You don't want to use string concatenation with parameters. It's a bad practice to get into (in Web applications this is a huge cause of SQL injection vulnerabilities). Take a look at [Insert command with parameters](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/Insertcommandwithparameters.htm) and use something like:

```
INSERT INTO DailyPrice
(Ticker,OpenPrice,ClosePrice,HighPrice,LowPrice,AdjustedClose,Volume,DateStamp)
VALUES
(@Ticker,@OpenPrice,@ClosePrice,@HighPrice,@LowPrice,@AdjustedClose,@Volume,@DateStamp)
```

Lastly, you should add a primary key. You could use (Ticker,DateStammp) for this but I personally favour technical primary keys, meaning a primary key that has no external meaning. An auto-increment integer field is the most common example of this. Adding (Ticker,DateSTamp) as a primary key will add the index I was referring to above. It's the index that really makes the difference.

Comment: I have to agree *in general* about using technical primary keys, but for this purpose it might just add an extra unneeded overhead. On the other hand, a timestamp doesn't make a particularly good key. I'm actually not completely convinced that a relational database is a good way to store this data at all, since there are no relations and the data is modelling something that is continuous-time-based in real life, not row based. But when you have a hammer... I guess it works.

Comment: Although my VB app is local only, I appreciate your help with parameters! My ASP.Net program (unrelated to this) is in dire need of it - I will redo with parameters!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, you also have a problem in that you are inserting rows one at a time. Far better to use bulk insert or an SSIS package. Never insert (or update or delete) large amounts of data by iterating through the rows. Databases are designed to work wioth sets of data and perform far better when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to create an index on your table. You're causing a complete table scan every time you want to add a new row (because of the `SELECT DateStamp FROM DailyPrice ... WHERE ...` statement), looking for some existing value.

Anyway, since you're checking for a record with an specific *DateStamp* and *Ticker* value for every insert, you could make **DateStamp** and **Ticker** the primary key of your table, that way, the database will index these two columns, and you won't need to do the `IF NOT EXISTS` part... the insert will fail if there is already a given key in the table. Keep in mind, however, that this will cause an exception in your VB.Net program, so you'll have to handle it.

Another thing you can do is to change the datatypes for the columns, specially the ones that are indexed. You could change **Ticker** to `nvarchar(X)` with X being some fixed value (`nvarchar(250`), for example), if you can estimate the length of the strings to be stored there. Also you could change **DateStamp** to `DateTime`.

Comment: I had no idea I could use 2 primary keys! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You *can't* have two primary keys. You can have a primary key that uses two columns though.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. In the SQL studio thingy, it showed 2 key symbols (one on each column), and I took that to mean 2 primaries. So this basically boils down to that primary key (the pairing of the 2 columns) has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of database problems:

- Instead of checking for the existence of a record that matches `DateStamp` and `Ticker`, you could [add a unique index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188783(SQL.90).aspx) on those columns. That would force the RDBMS to check for an existing record before inserting anything, and it will probably be a lot faster than your current version, because it will use an index and is optimized for this.
- Use some real data types and not `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Find out the appropriate data type for every column and reduce the max length of `varchar` columns to about what you actually expect to be in the database. This should make SELECTs and the built-in index management work faster.
- The code could be a little bit faster if you used a parameterized query and simply changed the parameter value. That way, you would not only get rid of that ugly string concatenation, but you would also not get in a problem if one of your CSV files contains "weird" data, ie. a `'` character which would blow your SQL query.

However, I would also double check your CSV reader code. What if the real problem is not even the database but your application needing too much memory and causing swapping?

> I always expected the rate of row addition to be constant over time, but obviously this is not so!

As you already discovered, it is not - and it might even get "worse" if you apply a lot of indexes to that table, since those kinda slow down INSERT statements.